# Compilation Error: Error:(81, 18) error: cannot find symbol method addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener)

Tags: android

My project was running well (and the backup project still doesn't produce this error) but when I added layout for **Conact_Us** page it produced this error. (Contact us activity is not throwing any error)
following is my Gradle build **Message**

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>       Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
>       Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'
>       :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:checkDebugManifest
>       :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Beta1Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Beta1Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Beta1Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Beta1Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Beta1Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComDaimajiaSliderLibrary115Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>       :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>       E:\Optasia\Optasia2\app\src\main\java\com\example\dell\optasia\WelcomeActivity.java
>       Error:(81, 18) error: cannot find symbol method addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener)
>       Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>       Information:BUILD FAILED
>       Information:Total time: 9.781 secs
>       Information:2 errors
>       Information:0 warnings
>       Information:See complete output in console

here is my code where the erro is occurring

```
    package com.example.dell.optasia;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.dell.optasia.MainActivity;
import com.example.dell.optasia.R;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            R.layout.welcome_slide3,
            R.layout.welcome_slide4};

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, HomeScreen.class));
    finish();
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
}
error at  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
```

following is my Gradle Built

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.optasia"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/activation.jar')

}
```

Comment: Add specific `playservice` required by your project do not add like this `  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'` and what is viewPagerPageChangeListener?

Comment: its a slider code i got from github. Nothing of my own. It didnt produce any of this error in my backup.

Comment: Error is not in your gradle file but in your MainActivity file because you set the viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener() but in your code not at where is your this method.

Comment: But there is no initialization of this Slider check in library - sample how to use that slider and then try to use it.

Comment: please share your whole code of your WelcomeActivity.jave class or else use this one also good for intro slider http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: i have shared the whole code. This is working totally fine in my backup with same libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are getting a ViewPager class in your code without the onPageChangeListener method defined.

You'll need to be using this import

```
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

I'd also recommend cleaning up your dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
}
```

Then, if these files reference your local project, here, then remove the v4 JAR

```
compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/mail.jar')
compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/activation.jar')
```

Those lines aren't necessary if your jar files are in the libs directory because of this line, which compiles all the jars in the libs.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: Yes i feel there is confusion in my dependencies. This helps alot. I am looking in to it and will inform if my issue is resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have added two versions of support library. Remove the jar version as I suspect that should be older version which does not have `addOnPageChangeListener`

**Remove**

`compile files('E:/Optasia/Optasia2/libs/android-support-v4.jar')`

Comment: removing this solved the problem i was facing ! Thank you so much !